# Jupyter Notebook Argparse Error in Anaconda Python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am new in Python.

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=upZfVyGNEfo&t=65s&ab_channel=TheSchoolofAutomation), I got error in Anaconda Jupyter Notebook.

- I only have anaconda and its 3.9 python.
- I did not install any Python from https://www.python.org/

When I add this code:

```py
import argparse
# set up cli domain argument
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Check domain for availability")
parser.add_argument("domain", type=str, help="Domain name to be checked")
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.domain)
```

I got this error

#### Error

```
usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] domain
ipykernel_launcher.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -f
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.
SystemExit: 2
C:\Users\Messi\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:3377: UserWarning: To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
  warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)
```

How can I fix this?

I also provide a [screenshot in this link.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVowq.png).

Thanks for your Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some libraries, anaconda and python do not have them automatically installed, thus you must install them manually. Ie, Pandas, Numpy, TKinter, Boto3, MatPlotLib etc must all be installed manually through the command prompt/terminal.

To install the argparse library on windows, try

```
conda install -c conda-forge argparse
```

In your window command prompt. For more details, see this link: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/argparse